# Operations on properties in Java Class

Tags: java, java-8

I have a class:

```
class Test{

 private int a;
 private int b;
 //setters, getters

}
```

I create 2 instances of type Test. They are initialized and fields are populated via 2 sources (say a file and database).

```
Test testFileValues = new Test();
Test testDBValues = new Test();
//code to populate the above 2 objects goes here where i read from file and db and populate above 2 objects using some logic.
```

After that I need to add each property from one class with the other and produce a sum of the 2 classes in a third result class.

So basically,

```
Test resultTest = new Test();
resultTest.setA(testFileValues.getA() + testDBValues.getA());
resultTest.setB(testFileValues.getB() + testDBValues.getB());
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this via Java 8 like lambda or streams? I thought of using reflection and getting the class attributes in a for loop and perform operations but that looks more tedious than my current solution.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your solution is as clear, obvious and efficient as it could be. You have nothing to worry about, and reflection is, as almost always, not something you should use.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a cleaner way to do this via Java 8 like lambda or streams?

No.

Your current solution is as clean as it gets.  Java cannot automatically infer that you want to treat all the variables the same and add them together or anything; nothing in Java 8 will help this.